# Выпадающее свеху окно на андроид

Tags: android, java

Добрый день.
В процессе создания приложения встала необходимость организации выпадающего свеху окна по клику на кнопку. То есть есть `Layout` со своим контентом, и необходимо чтобы по щелчку он выпадал сверху, но это должна быть не просто анимация, а то окно с которого оно вызывалось, а вызаваться он может везде, оставалось на месте а выпадающее было поверх.
Искал, гуглил но ничего толком не нашел.

Может кто сталкивался с подобной задачей?
Буду рад любой помощи!

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: заголовок жесть конечно

Comment: Согласен! Я не знаю как это называется, поэтому и заголовок такой)

Answer (score 1):

[Custom layout. Выплывающая панель + параллаксный скроллинг](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191586/) подойдет?

Так же могу предложить написать сервис, который бы показывал ваш Layout поверх всех активити, тут готовый пример: [creating a system overlay (always on top) button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android). Здесь то же кое-что: [how can i put my PopupWindow to system desk or other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734099/how-can-i-put-my-popupwindow-to-system-desk-or-other-app/3809160)!

Comment: Посмотрел. Первый вариант отлично подходит, но вот вопрос как по шелчку его вызывать?

Comment: @vanyamelikov я не смотрел, скачайте пример, попробуйте!

Comment: Скачал посмотрел! Он вызывается по жесту, а мне нужно отключить жест, и чтобы он вызывался по шелчку на кнопку в любом из активити!